# DateSeparator and TimeSeparator missing in DateTimeFormatInfo in .NET API for Windows Store Apps

Tags: .net, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

In the .NET API for Windows Store Apps DateTimeFormatInfo does not include the properties
DateSeparator and TimeSeparator. The reason is possibly that both allowed setting in the full API. But in case I need to get the current date or time separator (and I do), what could I possibly use instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) to get the info.

```
var dateSep = DateTime.Now.ToString("%/", dateTimeFormatInfo);
var timeSep = DateTime.Now.ToString("%:", dateTimeFormatInfo);
```